# Community Outreach: Be more liberal with Voting!

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, voting

I currently think of questions and answers as having three 'states'.

**Good**

This question is on topic, well thought out, properly articulated and is not a poll or trying to incite discussion

This answer focuses on key points and weighs both the pro's and con's of a choice. Perhaps with references to external sources as required.

**Bad**

This question is a poll, is attempting to incite discussion, is off-topic, poorly researched, poorly articulated or will provide little to the site.

This answer doesn't weigh the pros and cons, or doesn't source references, or seems like a guess and maybe doesn't even answer the question.

**Needs Improvement**

These types of questions and answers may have some aspects of the bad points and some aspects of the good points. With a little guidance and effort these posts could be brought into the realm of *good*

**So? What of it?**

What i currently see with questions and answers is the ones in the ticker for hot questions getting lots of up-votes from people outside of our usual community. Or maybe a really poor question being down-voted to -6 or -7 before being deleted.

But currently we have hundreds of questions and answers sitting at around -1, 0 or 1 votes despite having hundreds of views.

So this is a community outreach, Vote up those good questions! Vote down those bad ones, suggest improvements to the ones that need improvement!

I'm confident that every question and answer here will fall into one of these three groups, and every group requires action of some kind.

**Why would we bother?**

I'm so glad you asked me this, imaginary viewer!

The benefits of voting more liberally and suggesting improvements will give us a more active community. This also gives us a larger pool of view points to determine the exemplary answers from the mediocre.

With our seeming influx of new members visiting having many votes around makes it very easy to see which answers are good, which are bad, which are fantastic and which are terrible. If everything ranges from -1 to 1 on average its very hard to spot what's a bad question, and what's just vendetta voting. But it is **VERY** easy to spot the good and bad when the range varies from -10 to 10!

This also helps us discover your views and take them into consideration. If you think something is bad, vote it down, this shows us its bad and means its more likely going to be easily spotted for deletion or improvement by the community!

all in all, the votes are there to separate the exemplary from the terrible, don't be afraid to vote!

Comment: With a high percentage of questions being put On Hold, I wonder if that is a disincentive to vote? I'd want to hold off in my voting until I see the question "stabilize" so I know what I'm actually voting for.

Comment: I think you missed the *~meh~* state - That is an answer that is not good or bad and really no good way to improve it without completely changing the answer.  Those I think deserve no vote

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Once a post has been edited, you can always change your vote. If there are people who don't know that, then you may be right, that could be a disincentive to vote...

Comment: I doubt that most members are changing votes. I suspect the vast majority of folks are far more casual readers and voters. When they visit the site to read and see most of the top questions On Hold, I think that sends a message.

Comment: It's a huge pain to find posts you downvote which get edited and improved (or vice versa). Generally I only am able to do this if I post a reason (which I do often) and then someone responds with a comment which notifies me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the questions [from -2 to 2 in score, with over 500 views](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+score%3A-2..2+views%3A%3E500):

- [How to overcome perception problems and understand my work environment and my management accurately?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6687/how-to-overcome-perception-problems-and-understand-my-work-environment-and-my-ma)
- [Is a 30-second pause after a salary offer a good tactic?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7454/is-a-30-second-pause-after-a-salary-offer-a-good-tactic)
- [How to introduce yourself in a telephone interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-to-introduce-yourself-in-a-telephone-interview)
- [What kind of business fields are available to a programmer who no longer wants to program?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-kind-of-business-fields-are-available-to-a-programmer-who-no-longer-wants-t)
- [Negotiation for Fulltime Conversion After Internship](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/negotiation-for-fulltime-conversion-after-internship)
- [How can I get management to hold other employees accountable for their actions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9643/how-can-i-get-management-to-hold-other-employees-accountable-for-their-actions)
- [How can I prioritize and Organize my tasks and then plan my day effectively?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9337/how-to-plan-prioritize-and-organize-work-day-and-tasks-effectively)
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3739/im-not-a-software-engineer-any-more-but-what-am-i
- [How to renege implicit verbal acceptance of a job offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/how-to-renege-implicit-verbal-acceptance-of-a-job-offer)
- [What is the purpose of a recruitment agency?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-recruitment-agency)
- [My current boss asks surprising questions which haven't been asked by a boss before, how should I respond?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13308/my-current-boss-asks-surprising-questions-which-havent-been-asked-by-a-boss-bef)
- [Do I have any legal recourse regarding verbal job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/do-i-have-any-legal-recourse-regarding-verbal-job-offer)
- [Does "one month's notice period" mean 30 or 31 days?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/does-one-months-notice-period-mean-30-or-31-days)
- [How to tell my boss that I do not want to do a task that is too simple for my experience](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/how-to-tell-my-boss-that-i-do-not-want-to-do-a-task-that-is-too-simple-for-my-ex)
- [Is pressure on working while on sick leave considered mobbing?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/is-pressure-on-working-while-on-sick-leave-considered-mobbing)
- [Employee Poaching](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10358/employee-poaching)
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/stuck-in-boring-programming-jobs
- [Difference between Manager and Director](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/difference-between-manager-and-director)
- [How to convince colleagues about my point of view in a meeting?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8819/how-to-convince-colleagues-about-my-point-of-view-in-a-meeting)

8 of these questions are closed. They should almost certainly be downvoted (or have a reopen vote cast, if that is your cuppa). These questions are getting a reasonable amount of attention and are in the 'meh' zone [as Chad puts it](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/community-outreach-be-more-liberal-with-voting#comment3054_2036). 'meh' or not, don't you all want to get a bit closer to your [electorate badge](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate)?